# How to pass arguments to create_engine in Pylons application?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons

I'd like to customize database connection in Pylons application.
I'm interested in changing these arguments:

- pool_size
- pool_recycle

In SqlAlchemy the arguments are passed to *create_engine* call, like here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html?highlight=pool_size#sqlalchemy.create_engine

How can I change those params in Pylons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do it right in your ini file, it's been a while since I did pylons but IIRC, assuming you said yes to the sqlalchemy question when you created the project, all items prefixed with "slqalchemy." are given as keywords to the engine_from_config method in sqlalchemy. see the config/environment.py file for more.

```
sqlalchemy.url=<your db connection info>
sqlalchemy.pool_size= ??
sqlalchemy.pool_recycle= ??
```

Comment: You're definitely right. I found it is documented here:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/models.html#for-mysql
and even there is a note about 'mysql server has gone away' which is the reason i wanted to change that.